# How to extract a part of CString if one doesn't knew start and end index in c++?

Tags: c++

`CString` contains `name 17.02.1990 10:30 PM`, where name will be of any size. I need to get date alone like `17.02.1990`

Comment: Have you read the MSDN documentation for CString? It has member functions for extracting a substring.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms928955.aspx

Comment: @pra: You will not find documentation on `CString` on MSDN, unless you are willing to go with the Windows CE documentation in some language other than English (as evidenced by Neil Butterworth). You have to know, that the documentation you are looking for is for [CStringT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class) or [CSimpleStringT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class). That's not immediately obvious.

Comment: @IInspectable I suspect Neil Googled `CString::Mid`. If I search for `CString`, the first result is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx which points you to `CStringT` early on. Not ideal, but not too difficult to find either.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CString::Mid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#mid) class member to extract *nCount* characters, starting at index *iFirst*:

```cpp
CString datePart{ source.Mid(5, 10) };
```